# How does Puppet pass MFA?

Tags: unix, puppet, puppet-enterprise, puppetlabs-apache

If you need a password to copy files from one server to another, how does Puppet do it? Copying from master to client.
What't the technical detail? I am assuming it has to do with those permission codes?

Answer (score 2):

Puppet uses it's own SSL/HTTPS based protocol for transfer files between puppet master and agent. Puppet agent is running from privileged user, so it can place files in any place of system, which is specified by according manifest. 
So, you'll need privileges to start agent from root. And then it's agent, who deal with it.

Comment: In other words, Puppet doesn't pass MFA, it *bypasses* MFA.  After having been enabled to do so by a sufficiently privileged user.